# Match the string data inside a group - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| company|          id|ann_rtn_dt|share_class_nb|shrhldr_seq_nb|shrhldr_first_nm|shrhldr_mid_nm|shrhldr_sur_nm|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            NIEL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|               N|             C|          MORE|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            NEIL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NIMIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The whole dataframe can be grouped 2 distinct `company` column i.e. `SYNTE01` and `SYNTHE02`.

My use case is to do matching inside the `company`.

`STATUS_1` is set to `min` of `id`, when there is full match of `shrhldr_first_nm`, `shrhldr_mid_nm` and  `shrhldr_sur_nm` in the grouop.

`STATUS_2` is set to `min` of `id`, when there is match of first byte of `shrhldr_first_nm` and `shrhldr_mid_nm` in the group. And `shrhldr_sur_nm` matches exactly.

For eg. in `COMPANY` `SYNTHE01`, NIEL ANDREW HOPSON in row1 matches with NIEL ANDREW HOPSON in row4. The column `STATUS_1` is set to `min` of `id` column for both.

For eg. in `COMPANY` `SYNTHE01`, the first byte of NICOLE CLAIRE MORE in row2 matches with N C More in row3. The column `STATUS_2` is set to `min` of `id` column for both.

My output dataframe would look like below:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| company|          id|ann_rtn_dt|share_class_nb|shrhldr_seq_nb|shrhldr_first_nm|shrhldr_mid_nm|shrhldr_sur_nm|     STATUS_1|     STATUS_2|
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            NIEL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON| SYNTHE01_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE| SYNTHE01_3_1| SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|               N|             C|          MORE|             | SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            NEIL|        ANDREW|        HOPSON| SYNTHE01_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE01|SYNTHE01_3_2|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NICOLE|        CLAIRE|          MORE| SYNTHE01_3_1| SYNTHE01_1_2|
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_1|2022-11-28|             1|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_3_1|2022-11-28|             3|             1|          NIMIKE|              |        LOPSON|             |             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_1_2|2022-11-28|             1|             2|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
|SYNTHE02|SYNTHE02_2_1|2022-11-28|             2|             1|            MIKE|              |        LOPSON| SYNTHE02_1_1|             |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

We tried this in `Pyspark`, could not achieve  it. We are now trying to do it in `Pandas`. Please suggest any possible approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df` your dataframe you could try:

```py
df = df.fillna("")
grouped = df.groupby(["company", "shrhldr_first_nm", "shrhldr_mid_nm", "shrhldr_sur_nm"])
df["STATUS_1"] = grouped["id"].transform("min").where(grouped["id"].transform("size") > 1)
groups = ["company", df["shrhldr_first_nm"].str[0], df["shrhldr_mid_nm"].str[0], "shrhldr_sur_nm"]
grouped = df.groupby(groups)
df["STATUS_2"] = grouped["id"].transform("min").where(grouped["id"].transform("size") > 1)
df = df.fillna("")
```

General strategy: group over `company` and the *relevant parts* of the columns `shrhldr_first_nm`, `shrhldr_mid_nm` and `shrhldr_sur_nm`. *"relevant parts"* means:

- `STATUS_1`: full columns.
- `STATUS_2`: first character from the columns `shrhldr_first_nm` and `shrhldr_mid_nm`, full column `shrhldr_sur_nm`.

This does produce blocks of rows in which the grouping criteria are identical  (`grouped`). For each of these blocks `["id"].transform("min")` selects the minimal `id`. `.transform` makes sure the original index is preserved. Of interest are blocks that contain more than one row, therefore the mask `grouped["id"].transform("size") > 1` is used with `.where` to make sure only those rows are selected.

The new columns `STATUS_1` and `STATUS_2` for the slightly modified sample (without irrelevant columns)

```
    company            id shrhldr_first_nm shrhldr_mid_nm shrhldr_sur_nm
0  SYNTHE01  SYNTHE01_1_1             NIEL         ANDREW         HOPSON
1  SYNTHE01  SYNTHE01_3_1           NICOLE         CLAIRE           MORE
2  SYNTHE01  SYNTHE01_1_2                N              C           MORE
3  SYNTHE01  SYNTHE01_2_1             NIEL         ANDREW         HOPSON
4  SYNTHE01  SYNTHE01_3_1           NICOLE         CLAIRE           MORE
5  SYNTHE02  SYNTHE02_1_1             MIKE            NaN         LOPSON
6  SYNTHE02  SYNTHE02_3_1           NIMIKE            NaN         LOPSON
7  SYNTHE02  SYNTHE02_1_2             MIKE            NaN         LOPSON
8  SYNTHE02  SYNTHE02_2_1             MIKE            NaN         LOPSON
```

are

```
       STATUS_1      STATUS_2  
0  SYNTHE01_1_1  SYNTHE01_1_1  
1  SYNTHE01_3_1  SYNTHE01_1_2  
2                SYNTHE01_1_2  
3  SYNTHE01_1_1  SYNTHE01_1_1  
4  SYNTHE01_3_1  SYNTHE01_1_2  
5  SYNTHE02_1_1                
6                              
7  SYNTHE02_1_1                
8  SYNTHE02_1_1
```

I've changed `NEIL` in row 3 to `NIEL` - otherwise your explanation wouldn't be correct, imho. I also don't understand why your expected output for `STATUS_2` doesn't include row 0 and 3 with `SYNTHE01_1_1`?

Comment: thanks for providing the answer,  your assumption are also correct. Could you please explain what are you trying to do in the code.

Comment: @SDS Thanks for the feedback. I've added some explanations and hope they help.